# SQLPlus : Displaying full sql error for a multiple lines statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have insert statements generated from a database using Toad looking like this :

```
Insert into TXT
   (ID, STR)
 Values
   (23, 'test');
```

When one of this statement is in error, SQLPlus says :

```
Insert into TXT
*
ERREUR à la ligne 1 :
(...)
```

It always says "ligne 1" for all lines in errors, so I need to see the full line in error:

```
Insert into TXT (ID, STR) Values (23, 'test');
*
ERREUR à la ligne 1 :
(...)
```

is there a parameter or any way to get this displayed with SQLPlus ?

Comment: Use single quotes, not double, when specifying a string in SQL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `SET ECHO ON` in your script. Sql*Plus will echo on the terminal the commands that it plays.

When it reports an error, the query will be above it.

Comment: I have a "launcher.sql" script calling other scripts, I've added : "SET ECHO ON" and "set termout on" in my launcher.sql script and it didnt change display at all.

Comment: Ok, it was the best answer but something was missing : you have to launch sqlplus without the "-s" flag for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is quite what you're after, but using the 11g SQL*Plus client you can store them using [`set errorlogging`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2698945):

```
SQL> set errorlog on truncate
SQL> insert into dual -- don't do this really of course
  2  values (1, 2);
insert into dual -- don't do this really of course
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00913: too many values


SQL> select statement, message from sperrorlog;

STATEMENT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MESSAGE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
insert into dual -- don"t do this really of course
values (1, 2)
ORA-00913: too many values
```

As long as you commit you can see the errors in another session, too e.g. after your script exits. Requiring a commit is a bit of a shame; this seems like a candidate for an autonomous transaction, but I'm sure they had their reasons. You can query it in the same session anyway if you know to do so - it would be nice if you could do that automatically on error I suppose. Note that this also traps SQL*Plus errors (SP2-xxxxx) which are otherwise hard to deal with.

Tom Kyte has previously [written about this](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/new-thing-about-sqlplus.html), and it's in [this 11g top features article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-misc-091388.html) too.